# Gmail API PHP Get last message of email

Tags: php, gmail-api

I'm using the PHP Gmail API to poll for unread emails. When I find one, I'd like to get only the content in the last message of the email thread. So, here is an example thread I built between 2 of my email accounts:

```
==================================================
MESSAGE ID: 15e9f58a64c41d19
THREAD ID:  15e9f58a64c41d19
DATE:       1505911938000

MESSAGE:

This is an email. Deal with it
==================================================
MESSAGE ID: 15e9f60859f747dd
THREAD ID:  15e9f58a64c41d19
DATE:       1505912456000

MESSAGE:

It's okay. I forgive you

On Wed, Sep 20, 2017 at 8:52 AM, User1 <user1@gmail.com> wrote:

> This is an email. Deal with it
>

==================================================
MESSAGE ID: 15e9f60cdbebde04
THREAD ID:  15e9f58a64c41d19
DATE:       1505912471000

MESSAGE:

I don't care what you think. This is over
On 9/20/2017 9:00:57 AM, User 2 <user2@gmail.com> wrote:
It's okay. I forgive you

On Wed, Sep 20, 2017 at 8:52 AM, User 1 <user1@gmail.com [mailto:user1@gmail.com]> wrote:

This is an email. Deal with it
```

So, between each ==================== is a single message of a thread. I get this info like this:

```
function printThreads($service, $thread)
{
    // Print the labels in the user's account.

    $messages = $service->users_threads->get('me', $thread);

    foreach ($messages as $message)
    {
        $params = [];
        $params['format'] = 'full';

        $result = $service->users_messages->get('me', $message->getId(), $params);
        $payload = $result->getPayload();
        $parts = $payload->getParts();

        if (isset($parts[0]))
        {
            $body = $parts[0]['body']->data;
            $san = strtr($body, '-_', '+/');
            $decode = base64_decode($san);

            print "==================================================\n";
            print "MESSAGE ID: " . $message->getId() . "\n";
            print "THREAD ID:  " . $message->getThreadId() . "\n"; 
            print "DATE:       " . $message->getInternalDate() . "\n\n";
            print "MESSAGE:\n\n";
            print $decode;
            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

but, as can be seen in the print results, each message in the thread is appended by the previous messages in the thread. So, for my polling application to work, I'd like to get back only this from the last message in the thread:

"I don't care what you think. This is over"

Does the API allow me to do that in anyway? I've looked over the messages and threads stuff, but I don't see anything. My other option is to run a regex and split the file at the "On Wed, Sep 20, 2017 at 8:52 AM, User1  wrote:", but I don't think that'd be very reliable.

Comment: How are you separating each threads? 
With those dashes `============` or what ?

Comment: Actually `$service->users_threads->get()` is this function separating each thread based on dashes?

Comment: In the printThreads function above, I get all the messages from a single thread. I then loop through each and simply print out their information. I am printing out the dashes to show where each message in the thread starts and stops

Comment: Ok, that means you have an array of messages. Then just simply take the last message from the array. Did you try it?

Comment: The last message in the array has all the previous messages appended to it. So, in my example, there are 3 items in the array. The last one in my output has 3 messages of the thread in it

Comment: Now clear. Ok, if you have dashes in last message, just separate dashes and take last one. 
Do you want to take just the message "I don't care what you think. This is over" or everything there included time and others ?